# out of onResponse result NULL

Tags: java, android, json

so here is the thing , i got the data from JSON , everything works fine inside onResponse but outside it goes back null , ps : Constants.idcategory is static variable , when i use the AlertDialog inside the onResponse methode it works almost fine but i need to use it outside the onResponse , thanks you in advance

```
private void idCategory(String ip){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getString(R.string.login)).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<List<ListeCategories>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getIdCategory(ip);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ListeCategories>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ListeCategories>> call, Response<List<ListeCategories>> response) {
                final List<ListeCategories> chaines = response.body();
                for(ListeCategories chaine:chaines){
                    mots = chaine.getLiveTV().split(",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < mots.length; i++) {
                        Constants.idcategory.add(Integer.parseInt(mots[i]));

                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ListeCategories>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        String message = String.valueOf(Constants.idcategory.size());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();



    }
```

Comment: "...but i need to use it outside the onResponse." – Why, exactly? If it's just for neatness, you can put it into a separate method that's called from `onResponse()`, but no matter where you put it, you can't call it until `onResponse()` runs.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android) is useful to you :)

Comment: i need Constants.idcategory in another activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data outside `onResponse()` body is null because the method is asynchronous. The dialog is shown before response arrives, and therefore there is empty list.

You should wrap the dialog showing code in some method and call this method from `onResponse()` body. Be aware that `onResponse()` method is executed on background thread, maybe you will need main thread for showing the dialog.

```
private void idCategory(String ip){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getString(R.string.login)).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
    Call<List<ListeCategories>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getIdCategory(ip);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ListeCategories>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ListeCategories>> call, Response<List<ListeCategories>> response) {
            final List<ListeCategories> chaines = response.body();
            for(ListeCategories chaine:chaines){
                mots = chaine.getLiveTV().split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < mots.length; i++) {
                    Constants.idcategory.add(Integer.parseInt(mots[i]));

                }
                break;
            }
            showDialog()
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ListeCategories>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

private void showDialog() {
    String message = String.valueOf(Constants.idcategory.size());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();



}
```

Comment: but thanks i just got the answer am looking for it is about the background thing that was helpfull